# getting maven error while running the Selenium tests form Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a Maven project and written some Selenium TestNG scrips in it.
Jenkins installed on the Linux server and while I'm trying to run the Selenium tests from Jenkins getting this Maven error,

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
        Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
        org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.5:
          Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
            Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.47.215] failed: Connection timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Jenkins server failed to download a dependency from the Maven repository.

This is mentioned in the error message:

> Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.47.215] failed: Connection timed out

This may be a temporary connectivity problem with your server, so you could try again.

If this error keeps happening, then check with your network administrator that the Jenkins server has access to that hostname and port, as it may be blocked by a firewall.